# How to change Image inside canvas's Canvas.Left property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, canvas

simple question for you fellas.
I have an image inside a Canvas, with a Canvas.Left property i want to change
programaticly.
How do i do that?

Comment: By reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.left.aspx)?

Comment: No, actully by using SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, width/2); and that did not appear in documentation. thank you for the sarcastic comment though.

Comment: says SetLeft not SetValue, and when you seem to think this as a dumb question, i see this thread as a solution to someone asking the same question @ Google 1 day. think about it :)

Comment: @eric.itzhak Using Canvas.SetLeft is actually the "normal" way to handle this, which is mentioned in the documentation for Canvas.Left, when viewing C# samples.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: I do not get what you are saying, and in case you do not know how these `SetProperty` methods work: They are just wrappers which internally call `SetValue`, it makes no difference.

Comment: Dosen't matter, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`Canvas.SetLeft(theImage, newValue);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx)

This is the standard means of using [Attached Properties from Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#attached_properties_code).  When implementing an attached property (such as Canvas.Left), it's standard to include a static method that is named `SetPropertyName` for a given attached property named `PropertyName`.

Comment: Why the downvoting?  This will work, and do exactly as requested.  This is the "standard" means of using attached properties from code.

Comment: @H.B. Hrm. Well, thanks for at least saying why.  This is a proper answer to the question, at least ;)

Comment: @H.B. I seem to recall getting into a disagreement with you about this a while back.... downvote the question, not the answer. Otherwise you're giving bad information by making it seem that the answer posted is not valid. Anyways, +1 because this is the correct answer

Comment: @Rachel Yes - that's always my policy.  I don't care about the loss of rep., of course, but I do think a clear, valid answer to a poorly written question is still a useful contribution to the community.

Comment: @Rachel: This is a different issue actually. Of course i downvoted the question as well, and now removed the vote from the answer as it's useless, the comment is more important.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: The question is not poorly written, it's just not useful, and as i see it a better contribution than to answer it would be to vote for its closure as it keeps the noise down. By now it seems almost impossible to find relevant questions on SO because of all the useless ones which outnumber the good ones by more than 10 to 1.

Comment: This worked to solve an issue inside click event adding dynamic images to canvas that have MouseMove, MouseDown events. Had to set the Canvas.SetLeft(theImage, newValue); for the image getting added at click event. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081133/adding-child-image-to-canvas-with-settings-in-wpf-c-sharp/44081442#44081442 +1